# Child interface of generic interface IoC bindnig in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have base generic interface

```
public interface ICRUDStore<Model> where Model : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Model>> FindAsync();
    Task<Model> FindAsync(int id);
    Task UpdateAsync(int id, Model updatedRecord);
    Task DeleteAsync(int id);
    Task CreateAsync(Model record);
}
```

and it's child interface

```
public interface ICourseStore : ICRUDStore<Course>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Course>> FindByMenuIdAsync(int menuId);
}
```

where `Course` is basic model class.
I'm implementig this repository with `PgCourseStore : PgStore<Course>, ICourseStore` where `PgStore<Course>` is a base class for working with Postgres.

I have abstract base controller class

```
 public abstract class BaseController<Model, Store> : ApiController
                                        where Model : class
                                        where Store : ICRUDStore<Model>
 protected readonly Store store;
```

with basic CRUD methods and its child controller with special queries `CoursesController : BaseController<Course, ICourseStore>` where I need `store` variable to be `ICourseStore` to call special queries.

So when i'm trying to bind `PgCourseStore` with `ICourseStore` with different IoC containers (like DryIOC, Autofac) everything works fine when FindAsync methods are called from my base controller. But when i'm trying to call Update, Delete or Create methods i'm getting Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException whith message that ICourseStore doesn't have definition for CreateAsync method.
Yes, I can store `store` like ICRUDStore type and casting it when I need, but may be there is more beautiful solution?

**UPD:** `BaseController` looks like

```
public abstract class BaseController<Model, Store> : ApiController
      where Model : class
      where Store : ICRUDStore<Model>
{
    protected abstract Model Parse(dynamic model);

    protected readonly Store store;

    public BaseController(ICRUDStore<Model> store)
    {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        var records = await store.FindAsync();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, records);
    }

    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(dynamic value)
    {
        var model = Parse(value);
        await store.CreateAsync(model);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
}
```

And `CourseController`

```
public class CoursesController : BaseController<Course, ICourseStore>
{
    public CoursesController(ICourseStore store) : base(store) { }
}
```

So I don't see any meaningfull difference between using of Create* and Find* methods. Both of these methods are defined in my base `PgStore<Model>` class (not in PgCourseStore) while I'm binding just ICourseStore and PgCourseStore.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. Suppose that `CourseController` depends on `ICourseStore` via a constructor to set `store` and `PgCourseStore`, `CoursesController` are all registered to IoC container.

Comment: Different or conflicting assembly versions in the same project?

Comment: @BobDust yes, PgCourseStore binded with ICourseStore and all controllers registered. Even more, as I said Find* methods works fine and I can't figure out why. 'll add some updates to make situation more clear in 10 minutes.

Comment: @TravisIllig Don't get your question, sorry. Like referencing two dll's with same methods/classes/etc. in the same namespace? If so, then no. I'm not referencing any at all except of default WebApi's. Plus autofac or dryioc (not both at the same time).

Comment: @TonyYoung, how did you compile above updated `BaseController`? The parameter type in its constructor must be `Store`.

Comment: @BobDust oh, sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the `dynamic` type that caused runtime binding error. Changing to `object` could help you:

```
    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(object value)
    {
        var model = Parse(value);
        await store.CreateAsync(model);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So many troubles with dynamic type. Thanks!